# How do i turn off a Visual Studio refactor tool. (and use the resharper one)

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I'm using Visual Studio and ReSharper. When clicking a "switch" statement, sometimes a "black hammer" icon is displayed and sometimes it's a yellow lightbulb. Like this:

[image: icons in visual studio]

i'm not sure which one is which, but i think, one of the icons is displayed by visual studio, the other by resharper. (i assume the yellow one is resharper, because it has more funktionality and for design reasons.).

is there a way i can turn off the "black hammer" one alltogether? Or, is there a reproducible way to allways get the same icon? Right now i have no idea why sometimes the hammer comes up and the lightbulb other times.

Answer (score 0):

The 'bulb' and 'hammer' icons are both supplied by ReSharper (see [here](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2020/11/30/alt-enter-the-shortcut-for-everything/)). You can merge the Visual Studio features with ReSharper's by adjusting the `ReSahrper`->`Options...`->`Environment`->`Editor`->`Visual Studio Features` settings.

You can change the icon theme by adjusting `ReSharper`->`Options...`->`Environment`->`General`

Comment: I see, thank you. Any idea why it’s sometimes the hammer and sometimes the bulb? (I’m looking for a way to get the bulb consistently, because it has a feature for switches that I would like to use)

Comment: It's context related I believe. Depends on where you place your cursor.

Comment: That’s the point somehow. It’s always „close“ to the switch statement. I am looking for a way to reliably produce  these icon.

Comment: If the cursor stays on a code with a visual highlighting (in the case on the screenshot, it's three dots that represent a "Hint" severity for an inspection, but also there are more, like colored squiggles or greyed out "unused" code), you will see the light bulb which notifies you that a quick fix is avaialble. If you place a cursor on the code without visual highlighting, you will see the hummer icon, but only in case there are context actions available for this context.